# what is the most fundamental difference between SPIR-V and LLVM-IR?

Tags: llvm, spir-v

Spir-v and LLVM IR have the same granularity and can be converted to each other. May I ask why SPir-V is still so popular with LLVM IR? The fundamental difference between the two?

Comment: You mean, besides the fact that SPIR-V is directly consumed by two APIs for doing graphics and compute operations (Vulkan and OpenCL), while LLVM is not?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike SPIR-V, LLVM IR is:

- Unstable, changing every LLVM release
- Neither forwards nor backwards-compatible in textual form
- Only backwards-compatible in binary form — newer LLVM versions can't produce binary IR that older versions can consume
- Complex and irregular structure
- Difficult to read or write without creating a dependency on LLVM, which is a massive project
- Not standardised
- Highly specific to LLVM's needs as a compiler, not being suited to other compilers or purposes other than an internal representation
- Limited extensibility (intrinsics and custom metadata exist, but they don't look or behave like the built-in instructions)
- Not portable (IR encodes platform-specific characteristics)
- Does not directly support many features needed by GPUs: textures, images, buffers, attributes, control over warp divergence, subgroup operations, variable precision…

Many projects have tried to use LLVM bitcode as a “universal bytecode” and many have regretted it. SPIR-V itself was created to replace SPIR which was based on LLVM IR.

The most important difference though is that Vulkan and OpenGL can directly consume SPIR-V, and SPIR-V is usable for shaders, not just compute kernels.

Answer (score 1):

LLVM-IR is a very coherent single IR threading through the majority layers of the compiler stack and the LLVM-IR focuses very much as a means for compiler transformations. SPIR-V is actually a mix of multiple things. For instance, the SPIR-V memory model was built on the foundation of the C++ memory model, but ended up diverging in a number of places. Hence, an obvious addition to the answer by Yugr is, beside instruction set, a fundamental difference is a memory model.